# Disable hiding of hide keyboard button on an onscreen keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard

I would like to disable or hide the hide button on an onscreen keyboard. I would only hide the onscreen keyboard programmatically.

Comment: Why is this in the user's interests?

Comment: yes...changes is made when user press enter key and keyboard is hidden...if the user directly hides the keboard there will be no changes made...

Comment: Since not all soft keyboards have an "enter key", you need to fix your app to not depend on one. Then, you will no longer need to "disable or hide the hide button on an onscreen keyboard".